# Local storage doesn't work after submitting data on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to keep the values of the rangeSlider after refreshing the page, as the selected range is reset. Local storage in my case for some reason doesn't work.

HTML Markup:

```
<input type="text" class="js-range-slider" name="my_range" value="" data-min="100" data-max="4000" data-from="1000" data-to="2000"/>
<input type="hidden" id="startPrice" name="startPrice" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="endPrice" name="endPrice" value="" />
```

```
<button class="filter-btn_send filter-btn_send--active" type="submit">Select</button>
```

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        if (localStorage.getItem('startPrice')) {
            $('.js-range-slider').data('from', localStorage.getItem('startPrice'));
            $('#startPrice').attr('value', localStorage.getItem("startPrice"))
        }
    
        if (localStorage.getItem('endPrice')) {
            $('.js-range-slider').data('to', localStorage.getItem('endPrice'));
            $('#endPrice').attr('value', localStorage.getItem("endPrice"))
        }
    
        $('.filter-btn_send filter-btn_send--active').submit(function () {
    
            let startPrice = $('#startPrice').attr('value');
            let endPrice = $('#endPrice').attr('value');
            localStorage.setItem('startPrice', startPrice);
            locacStorage.setItem('endPrice', endPrice);
    
        });
}
```

[image]

UPD! My solution: https://codepen.io/funn1k1/pen/qBqMmgx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**submit events**

Submit events are fired on form objects, not buttons or input elements that trigger submission (as covered in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event). The following snippet shows that, as posted, the submit handler is not called by monitoring "submit" events on the submit button - the expected outcome is that only the form submit handler will be called:

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
       console.log( "form submit handler called");
       e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('input').submit( function(e) {
       console.log( "submit button handler called");
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<form>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

**beforeunload event**

The ["beforeunload" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) can be monitored to save slider values when the page is unloading, even if the form has not been submitted. As a code pattern example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        // get values from range widget
        let startPrice = "1000" // example only
        let endPrice = "1174"   // example only
        // save in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('startPrice', startPrice);
        localStorage.setItem('endPrice', endPrice);
    });
 });
```

Note this doesn't include code to create, set or get the values of dual pointer jQuery-UI [range widgets](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range).

Comment: What if I don't need to reverse the behavior of the form and submit the form to the server, but still keep the ionRangeSLider values after refreshing the page?

Comment: I have several filters on this button and the data should be sent to the server with the page update. e. preventDefault () cancels the behavior. But I need the value from the range I selected not to be reset after the page refresh (for example 1000 - 1700, by default the slider has a value of 1000-2000).

Comment: After refreshing the page, the slider will reset.

Comment: Check my solution!

Comment: You can do that, or you can use the onChange event.